# How to embed solid Gauge using highcharts inside a div of a specific size

Tags: css, highcharts

I have created a Solid Gauge chart using Highcharts. Now, I want to fit the chart inside a grid div which takes size of 300px or auto. When I try to put the code inside the div, it takes a lot of white space up and down of the chart.I tried to inspect it and it is showing that the SVG image is taking most of the space. I don't understand how to make the chart fit in the div.I am new to HighCharts, any help would be appreciated.

```
    <div id="container" style="height: 300px;">
</div>

$(function() {

  var rawData = 100,
    data = getData(rawData);

  function getData(rawData) {
    var data = [],
      start = Math.round(Math.floor(rawData / 10) * 10);
    data.push(rawData);
    for (i = start; i > 0; i -= 1) {
      data.push({
        y: i
      });
    }
    return data;
  }

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'solidgauge',
      marginTop: 0
    },

    title: {
      text: ''
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: rawData,
      style: {
        'font-size': '60px'
      },
      y: 200,

    },

    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },

    pane: [{
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: [{ // Track for Move
        outerRadius: '100%',
        innerRadius: '70%',
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.1).get(),
        borderWidth: 0,
        shape: 'arc'
      }],
      size: '100%',
      center: ['50%', '65%']
    }, {
      startAngle: -180,
      endAngle: 180,
      size: '95%',
      center: ['50%', '65%'],
      background: []
    }],

    yAxis: [{

      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      labels: {
        enabled: true
      },     
      stops: [
        [0, '#fff'],
        [0.1, '#0f0'],
        [0.2, '#2d0'],
        [0.3, '#4b0'],
        [0.4, '#690'],
        [0.5, '#870'],
        [0.6, '#a50'],
        [0.7, '#c30'],
        [0.8, '#e10'],
        [0.9, '#f03'],
        [1, '#f06']
      ]
    }, {
    }],

    series: [{
      animation: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      borderWidth: 0,
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      radius: '100%',
      innerRadius: '70%',
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dt4wu39e/1/

Comment: Hi @Jayesh_K, Could you describe more precisely what the final result should look like? I think that the most appropriate solution in this case would be to adjust the height of the container to the plot area.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I have managed to get the solid gauge inside the div. But then while scrolling the screen, the solid gauge is floating over the fixed header.

Comment: Hi @Jayesh_K, You probably need to set correct `z-index` CSS style for the header. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/95jhwn06/

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element in which the chart is located has `z-index: 0;`, so you need to set higher `z-index` for the header:

```
header {
    z-index: 1;
    ...
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/95jhwn06/